# I want to know how to distribute the index values of multiple tables created with the "<c: forEach>" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

There is no problem in selecting a column from a table and outputting its contents. However, when outputting contents from two or more tables, there is a problem that the index of the value of the checked position overlaps. In the example below, if RESI_COST, which is the sixth column of the above table, is checked, FP_CAREER, which is the sixth index of the table below, is automatically selected. If OCCP_GRP_1, which is the eighth index of the table below, is checked, The eighth index, FP_CAREER, is also checked.

[image]

[image]

The code below creates the multiple tables.

```
<body>

    <c:forEach var="j" begin="0" end="${rData.size()-1}">



    <table id="sum_table" border="1">
         <thead>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="colName" items="${rData.get(j).colNames}">
                    <c:forEach var="colNameValue" items="${colName}">
                        <th><input class="chkCol" name="chkColnames" type="checkbox">
                            <label class="chkCol" for="chkColnames">${colName}</label></th>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="0"
                end="${fn:length(rData.get(j).data[0])-1}">
                <c:if test="${i le 1000}">
                    <c:set var="row" value="${rData.get(j).data}" />
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="data" items="${row}">
                            <td>${data[i]}</td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>      
  </c:forEach>
</body>
```

The following code retrieves the index value and outputs the information of the checked column.

```
    $(document).on('click', '#confirm', function() {
           var index = [];

           $('#col_table').html('');

           $('#sum_table thead tr input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
             index.push($(this).closest('th').index());
           });

           var thead = $('<thead>');
           $('#sum_table thead tr th').each(function() {
             if (jQuery.inArray($(this).index(), index) != -1) {
               thead.append($('<th>' + $(this).text() + '</th>'));
               //console.log($(this).text());
             }
           });


           var tbody = $('<tbody>');
           $('#sum_table tbody tr').each(function() {
             var tr = $('<tr>');
             $(this).find('td').each(function() {
               if (jQuery.inArray($(this).index(), index) != -1) {
                 tr.append($('<td>' + $(this).text() + '</td>'));
                 //console.log($(this).text());
               }
             });
             tbody.append(tr);
           });
           $('#col_table').append(thead);
           $('#col_table').append(tbody);
         });
```

If you solve the problem of overlapping index values, I would really appreciate it.